Help me out with the next body weight exercise which is complimentary to push ups?
I do a lot of aerobic exercise and I finally added some resistance training. The only thing I do is push-ups. My simple plan is three sets of about eight to failure. There's no chance I can do a real push-up yet so I do angle push-ups that is to say on stairs or even a wall. I adjust the "weight" so to speak by adjusting my angle, I choose a "weight" where I fail at about 8 or 9 reps as mentioned. I concentrate on good form and for each rep I use s "3 seconds / 1 second / 3 seconds" approach - because I read that somewhere. I do this on alternate days. I eat a good amount of protein as appropriate.
I love doing my push-ups and I hope one day I can work towards doing a real flat floor push-up.
I do a variety of that form of push-up, ie hands at slightly different widths, grips.
But I guess push-ups focus on one particular group of muscles.
Please tell me one good bodyweight exercise I can add for the arm/upper body muscles I'm missing. Thank you.

Site seems a little slow these days!  I'll add a bounty !

Since push up is mainly a push exercise, the obvious choice would be pull up to complement them. Under a table or something at first to make them easier if needed.
Body weight rows could work too, but you would need additional equipment (e.g. rings).
And once your comfortable with your exercises check their variations, they can be great to keep them fun and challenging, and to target other muscles that could be a little left out.

Great info, so indeed by "pull up" you mean basically find a bar (or similar) and pull myself up.   You're saying I could do that on an angle (since there's no chance I could do a "normal" pullup) rather like I do angled pushups - I never thought of it

Suggestion for additional equipment purchase: There are chinning bars that can be mounted in doorways. Some come with two pairs of mounting brackets. The O/P could install one pair at chin-up / pull-up height and the other pair at body weight rows height.

@max and old dog, by "pull up exercises" ... for example, say I simply stood there with my arms by my side, holding in my hand(s) 1 or 2 dumbbells (or perhaps just a bar, or really any weight) and "lifted the weight up vertically" (perhaps to navel height, say) ........ is that a "pull exercise".  I'm struggling a little to understand "pull exercises".  What about this, lay face down on a bench or such, lifting dumbbells upwards from the ground towards my torso?

are these body weight rows ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGsiKMi9pbU

You would still be pushing the weight up in example one, in the other example you'd be pulling. You have pushing muscles (triceps, pecs, quads,..) to push away from you and pulling muscles (biceps, laterals, hamstrings,...) to pull towards you. And one is an antagonist to the other (both would contract if you flex without weights) so it's better to try to work both.

Yes these are, as for pull up, you could do theme more angled at first to make them easier. Or use a resistance band to get you started, it really depends on the equipment you have at home.
And good suggestion from Old Dog Programmer, that's what I use at home, easy to install and it doesn't damage the door. But I've used stairs, tables, counter and others in the past, don't let a lack of equipment stop you.

Since push up is mainly a push exercise, the obvious choice would be pull up  Brilliant.  Thanks to you @Max I have now discovered surely the world's greatest exercise, "body weight rows" - lay on a floor face up, have a bar or something above your face, and pull yourself up and down.  Incredible.

Sent a small bounyt here, thanks @Max !

If you want to work the entire upper body, there's a lot missing. Push-ups target mainly chest and triceps, depending on the variation you do.
What's missing:

back
shoulders
abs
biceps

What you could do:

back: banded rows, scapular push-ups, body weight rows (under a table or hanging from a door with bedsheets), pull-ups (there are progressions you can follow with negative pull-ups and bands until you develop the strength to perform a regular pull-up)
shoulders: pike push-ups, wall walks (progressing into a handstand shoulder press)
abs: crunches and sit ups (there are so many variations), leg / knee raises
biceps: chin ups, bodyweight curls, reverse grip pushups...
chest, shoulders, triceps, and biceps: dips

These are just some examples, the internet is filled with calisthenics exercises for the whole body.
I highly recommend getting at least 2 resistance bands (with different resistances - i'd suggest one medium and one medium-harder, you'll get past the ones too easy very fast), it will increase your exercise selection tenfold for everything.
If you can add weights of any kind (a big water bottle, rice bags, anything) then you will also have more options.

Wonderful information, am absorbing TY!

Such a great answer, it's silly you can't split a bounty on the site!  TY so much!

@Fattie glad you enjoyed it. you can only mark one answer as accepted even if when there's not just one "correct" answer, but that's the way it works. I'll gladly take an upvote :)

Did that for sure!  :)
